# Network activity indicator when app goes from suspended state to active state (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an iPhone app that in some situations, must get some data from the internet when it becomes active. As it takes several seconds, I would like the user to see an activity indicator and not only the screenshot the system saved when the app went background state.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Comment: I'm getting the data from the internet in applicationDidBecomeActive

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIApplication's networkActivityIndicatorVisible on the applicationWillEnterForeground method to show the status bar indicator.

Comment: It doesn't work. The indicator appears when the app got the data from the internet. Not while it's getting it... Obrigado!

Comment: Try starting a background task. Search the docs for it. De nada!